# Is using notifyChange on multiple URIs ever correct in a ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

**Given two URIs:**

1. URI that is used in a ContentProvider's query method to retrieve multiple things:

   content://my-authority/things
2. URI used in a ContentProvider's update method which points to a single thing (same URI retrieves thing 123 if used with the query method):

   content://my-authority/thing/123

**My Question:** 
In the update method is it correct to notifyChange twice, once for each URI above?

**What led me to ask:**
If a ListView of things is automatically kept in sync with SQLite data (via. SimpleCursorAdapter, LoaderManger.LoaderCallbacks and the first URI) if thing 123 is updated and only notifies for that id then the ListView does not get notified/reflect the update.

I'm sure I've misunderstood something and that there's a more elegant solution..

Answer (score 2):

You only need to notifyChange for the  second URI (if updating).  If inserting you notifyChange the first URI.